# "Ant debug" output always shows no changes. How can I force apkbuilder to build APK?

Tags: android, ant

When I type "ant debug" on Jenkins, I always get message like :

- [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
- [dex] No new compiled code. No need to convert bytecode to dalvik format.
- [aapt] No changed resources or assets.
- [apkbuilder] No changes. No need to create apk.

The same command *from my local computer* against the same code from Eclipse does not output the messages above.  And it always finds modified input and creates an apk with debug key correctly from command-line.  My goal is to create an APK with debug key on Jenkins also.

Any idea why "ant debug" is showing the output as following? Is there a way to force apkbuilder to create an apk?

```
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input:  /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/bin/classes
      [dex] input: /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/libs/Robotium.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed Robotium-764572c80737d765208bdb367579ac89.jar <- /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/libs/Robotium.jar
      [dex] No new compiled code. No need to convert bytecode to dalvik format.

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] No changed resources or assets. Settings_Tests_New.ap_ remains untouched

-package:
[apkbuilder] No changes. No need to create apk.

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Run cancelled: no changes to input file         /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/bin/Settings_Tests_New-debug-unaligned.apk
     [echo] Debug Package: /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/bin/Settings_Tests_New-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/buildmaster/.jenkins/workspace/my-ci-job-name/bin/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: You could always clean before building with "ant clean"

Answer (score 0):

I do

```
rm -rf bin/* gen/*
```

then build

Answer (score 0):

You can clean by using this command before building :

> ant clean

Also if you wish to touch all files to change timestamp us this command. Then all files will rebuild:

> touch `find .`

Hope this helps

Comment: back quote is not getting supported while typing here. you need to add back quote before and after "find ."

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following target to my central build.xml to clean and build with one command:

```
<target name="rebuild" depends="clean, release" />
```